# How to use Regexp to retrieve URL where link text has number in the bracket

Tags: regex, testing, xpath, selenium, automation

I want to retrieve all links from the page, where link text is in the below format.

(**[10](http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=surat&start=0&all=no&cat=/Top/Regional/Asia/Thailand/Provinces/Surat_Thani/Ko_Samui/Travel_and_Tourism/Lodging/Resorts)**) Now I tried using below method but it didn't work.

There are many similar links available on the same page where number is not in sequence and also there are many repeated numbers for the link text, so I want to first collect such web element and then using attribute I can get the URL.

Similar to this page.
[**http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=surat&start=0&type=more&all=no&cat=**](http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=surat&start=0&type=more&all=no&cat=)

I want the link after we click on those numbers present in the bracket.

```
List<WebElement> catLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div[@id='doc']/div[@id='bd-cross']/ol/li[1]/a[2]"));  
for (WebElement catLink : catLinks) {
    System.out.println(nLink + ". " + catLink.getAttribute("href")); 
}
```

Link XPath is:

```
//html/body/div[@id='doc']/div[@id='bd-cross']/ol/li[***1***]/a[2]
```

Using Above XPath I can get the first link URL. Now What I can do to get all links URL.

I tried using regexp :

```
//html/body/div[@id='doc']/div[@id='bd-cross']/ol/li[\\d\\.\\*]/a[2]
```

But it is not working.

I also tried using below method.

```
List<WebElement> catLinks = driver.findElements(By.linkText("\\d\.\*"));  
for (WebElement catLink : catLinks) {
    System.out.println(nLink + ". " + catLink.getAttribute("href")); 
}
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now What I can do to get all links
>   URL.
>
> I triedn using regex :
>
> ```
> //html/body/div[@id='doc']/div[@id='bd-cross']/ol/li[\\d\\.\\*]/a[2]
> ```

Nop. Use:

```
/html/body/div[@id='doc']/div[@id='bd-cross']/ol/li/a[2]
```

Less is more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the `/html/body/` in the xpath locator, this will just make it more fragile if the page structure changes. Try this much simpler xpath locator: `id('bd-cross')//li/a[2]`

Comment: `id()` XPath function really need the presence and support of DTD. Also, when the schema is well known, the use of `//` operator is discourage because its performance (it traverse the complete descendant tree even after matching the desired node).

Comment: I agree. we should not use **/html/body** in the XPath, the best XPath that we should use.. `//div[@id='bd-cross']/ol/li/a[2]`